# Keeping Data Fresh via Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

What is the proper way to keep data slices refreshed? Imagine I have a table with various column, but importantly a `DATE_CREATED` and a `DATE_MODIFIED` column.

If my data slicing strategy is based on `DATE_CREATED`, I could periodically reprocess old slices. This follows the ADF guidance of "repeatability". I don't think ADF has a way of doing this automatically, but I could externally trigger the refresh via the API (I'm guessing.) This seems like perhaps the most correct way, but given that ADF doesn't seem to support this as a feature, it makes me feel like there's a better way of doing it ... it also seems mildly wasteful.

If my data slicing strategy is based on `DATE_MODIFIED`, I run into issues with the ADF activities not being repeatable. An old slice, when refreshed, would give different results because rows that were within the window may have moved to a different window. On the other hand, the latest slice would always catch rows that have changed. The other issue is preventing row duplication. The pre-activity clean up actions would need to somehow be able to clean up records in the destination table prior to the copy. Or some type of UPSERT method must be employed.

The final option is to `TRUNCATE` the destination table every day. This is fine for smaller tables but has its own downsides, (1) we're not really "slicing" at all anymore. This is just scorched earth. (2) Any time any slice is being processed, all downstream slices from all dates are in danger of failing, due to the table being blown away. (3) practically impossible if your table has any respectable amount of data in it.

No option seems excellent but the first option seems better. Looking for advice from someone who has solved this problem or is experienced with ADF.

Comment: To try an understand what you are aiming to achieve a little better can you explain __why__ you want to "periodically refresh old slices"? A slice is a state at a given point in time, unless there was a failure or some corruption of the data why rerun it?

Comment: The idea being that database records mutate over time, and you have to process them again, whether you do that by them leaving one slice and entering another (i.e. modified date change), or by rerunning old slices, is the question. I think slicing by modified date is probably the most correct, as it will result in all data being captured. The only challenge is processing the merging/inserting (i.e. upsert) on the copy sink side. That is another challenge all together, and probably involves some stored procedures ... Does that make sense? Thanks for helping out